# How to pull out specific rows from two data frames with different dimensions and produce multiple .csv files?

Tags: r, sqlite

Data frame one.

```
  structure(list(trial_id = c(2022L, 2023L, 2123L, 2184L, 3883L, 
4434L), ctri_number = c("CTRI/2018/02/011794 ", "CTRI/2017/08/009517 ", 
"CTRI/2019/05/019036 ", "CTRI/2017/12/010935 ", "CTRI/2017/09/009746 ", 
"CTRI/2016/06/007055 "), name = c("National Institute of Allergy and Infectious Diseases NIAIDMaryland USA", 
"Jawaharlal Nehru Medical College", "KLEU Ayurveda Pharmacy", 
"Amgen Inc", "Dr Arunkumar", "ALVAS EDUCATION FOUNDATION"), type_of_sponsor = c("' Government funding agency '", 
"' Government medical college '", "' Research institution '", 
"' Pharmaceutical industry-Global '", " Other [Self sponsored] '", 
"' Private hospital/clinic '"), address = c("' USA '", "' Jawaharlal Nehru Medical College, Aligarh Muslim University, Aligarh-202001 '", 
"' KLEU Ayurveda Pharmacy, Khasbhag, Belgaum, Karnataka '", "' One Amgen Center Drive\n\n\nThousand Oaks, CA USA\n\n\n91320 '", 
"' Room no 32 ,Department of Periodontics , Government Dental college , Trivandrum '", 
"' ALVAS EDUCATION FOUNDATION ALVAS COLLEGE OF PHYSIOTHERAPY\n\n\nMoodabidri - 574227\n\n\nSouth Canara District\n\n\nKarnataka '"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Data frame two.

```
    structure(list(distinctOrganizations = c("A AMMU", "A and U tibbia college and hospital", 
"A Arumuga kani", "A KIREETI", "AAMIR ZUBAIR SHAIKH", "Aansu Susan Varghese"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Using all the data fields from data frame 2(distinctOrganizations) I have to pull out the rows from data frame one which match the values in the name column.

However, each data field should produce a specific .csv file.

How can I achieve this?

---

Possible Outcome- A CSV file similar to the image.

[image: The image is of CSV file which contains all the rows related to AIIMS and its variants only. I need CSV file different for each such name.]

Comment: @RonakShah, the image is screenshot of a csv file which contains all the rows related to the  AIIMS only.

Comment: Could you provide the example of data produced from your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Your example data don't match any lines (`df2` doesn't provide any names contained in your example `df1`).

If I got your question right, you could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)

df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = c("name" = "distinctOrganizations")) %>% 
  split(f = .$name) %>% 
  walk(~write_csv(.x, paste0(unique(.x$name), ".csv")))
```

1. We use an `inner_join` to remove all elements from `df1` that don't have a match in `df2`
2. Then we `split` the resulting data.frame by name, creating a new data.frame for each (distinct) organization
3. Finally we use `purrr`'s `walk` function to write a `.csv`-file for each of these organizations. This produces `.csv`-files like `Amgen Inc.csv` or `ALVAS EDUCATION FOUNDATION.csv`.

**Note:** The `address` column contains some line breaks (`\n`). You should consider removing them, those could cause trouble in your `.csv` and in your next steps working with those. There are also some white spaces in column `type_of_sponsor` (at the beginning and the end) you perhaps want to remove.

[image]

#### Data

I modified `df2` to get two matches:

```
df2 <- structure(list(distinctOrganizations = c("Amgen Inc", "A and U tibbia college and hospital", 
"ALVAS EDUCATION FOUNDATION", "A KIREETI", "AAMIR ZUBAIR SHAIKH", 
"Aansu Susan Varghese")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```